# How to use a jobject array ? (Jni)

Tags: java, parsing, object, java-native-interface

In fact, I call a c++ function :

> JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_main_JniFunctions_testObject  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray objArray){....}

And what I'd like to do, is get back the original object's values. Considering the java code declaration for this object :

```
jniFct.testObject(new Object[][]
        {   
            {"testTable"},
            {0, 0.0, "aaa"},
            {1, 1.1, "bbb"},
            {2, 2.2, "ccc"}
        });
```

In exemple, get the value from the third row in the second column.

Anybody's got an idea on how to do it ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
jobject row = env->GetObjectArrayElement(objArray, 2);
jobject value = env->GetObjectArrayElement((jobjectArray)row, 1);
const char* cvalue = env->GetStringUTFChars((jstring)value, 0);
```

Comment: thank you but it gives me that error ::                  >IntelliSense: a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char*"                                                           And if I change the """char*""" to a """string""", it gives me that kind of value """<ü """ so .....

Comment: Compile errors would be more interesting to see. I think, you need to use `const char* cvalue`. I'll edit the answer...

Comment: Still got a question ! ^^ Is there anyway for the c++ code to know the data type (exemple : string, int, double, ...) so that I could place it into the good variable type ? Or is there a generic type that I could use to stock those variables ??